# Neural Network for Regression using PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to implement a Neural Network for predicting the h1_hemoglobin in PyTorch. After creating a model, I kept 1 in the output layer as this is Regression. But I got the error as below. I'm not able to understand the mistake. Keeping a large value like 100 in the output layer removes the error but renders the model useless as I am trying to implement regression.

Data:
[image: Data]

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
##### Creating Tensors
X_train=torch.tensor(X_train)
X_test=torch.tensor(X_test)
y_train=torch.LongTensor(y_train)
y_test=torch.LongTensor(y_test)
```

```
class ANN_Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,input_features=4,hidden1=20,hidden2=20,out_features=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.f_connected1=nn.Linear(input_features,hidden1)
        self.f_connected2=nn.Linear(hidden1,hidden2)
        self.out=nn.Linear(hidden2,out_features)
    def forward(self,x):
        x=F.relu(self.f_connected1(x))
        x=F.relu(self.f_connected2(x))
        x=self.out(x)
        return x

loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = 0.01)

epochs = 500
final_losses = []
for i in range(epochs):
    i = i + 1
    y_pred = model.forward(X_train.float())
    loss=loss_function(y_pred, y_train)
    final_losses.append(loss.item())
    if i%10==1:
        print("Epoch number: {} and the loss: {}".format(i, loss.item()))
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your response variable h1_hemoglobin looks like continous response variable. If that's the case please change the Torch Tensor Type for `y_train` and `y_test` from `LongTensor` to `FloatTensor` or `DoubleTensor`.

According to the Pytorch docs, `CrossEntropyLoss` is useful for classification problems with a number of classes. Try to change your `loss_function` from `CrossEntropyLoss` to a more suitable one for your continuous response variable `h1_hemoglobin`.

In your case, the following might do it.

```
y_train=torch.DoubleTensor(y_train)
y_test=torch.DoubleTensor(y_test)
...
...
loss_function = nn.MSELoss()
```

[Pytorch MSELoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MSELoss.html?highlight=mseloss#torch.nn.MSELoss)

[Pytorch CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html?highlight=crossentropy#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss)

Comment: Please see the answer for @Aditya for a more detailed answer about your error message

Answer (score 1):

Since you are performing regression, the `CrossEntropyLoss()` internally implements the `NLLLoss()` function. The `CrossEntropyLoss()` expects `C` classes for `C` predictions but you have specified only one class. The `NLLLoss()` tries to index into the prediction logits based on the ground-truth value. E.g., in your case, the ground-truth is a single value 14. The loss step tries to index into the 14th logit of your predictions to get its corresponding value so that it can compute the negative log likelihood on it, which is essentially - `-log(probability_k)` where k is the index that the ground-truth outputs. Since you have only logit in your predictions, it throws an error - *index out of bounds*.

For regression problems, you should consider using distance based losses such as `MSELoss()`.

Try replacing your loss function - `loss_function = CrossEntropyLoss()` with `loss_function = MSELoss()`